# Provider org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversIntegrator not a subtype tomcat 8

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, jakarta-ee, hibernate-envers

so i am using the jar hibernate-envers 5.1.14 and hibernate-core 5.4.14 with tomcat 8
and i am facing this exception :

```
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversIntegrator not a subtype
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:340)
at org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:40)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:213)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildBootstrapServiceRegistry(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:366)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:167)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:150)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
... 27 more
```

after some investigation the exception is throwen when executing this line in IntegratorServiceImpl class

```
for ( Integrator integrator : classLoaderService.loadJavaServices( Integrator.class ) )
```

and as i know EnversIntegrator implements Integrator interface from hibernate-core
here is a snip of code from EnversIntegrator

```
import org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator;
import org.hibernate.service.spi.SessionFactoryServiceRegistry;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

public class EnversIntegrator implements Integrator {
  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(EnversIntegrator.class);
```

**PS : I am 100% that i don't have multiple Hibernate jars version in my application or in the server**

Answer (score 1):

But you are using a hibernate-envers version that is not compatible with the hibernate-core version that you are using. The versions of the two must match as they are always released together.